# Creating a link and got error : "Uncaught ReferenceError: doCreateFriend is not defined"

Tags: javascript, android

So I created a WebView on Android with a link in it, but the link is not functional. To know why, I copy/paste the html code on a browser and when I click on the link, I get the error "**Uncaught ReferenceError: doCreateFriend is not defined**".

I searched and I don't know why it doesn't recognize the function.

Here is my code :

```
<body>
<div>
  <p><a href="#" onclick="doCreateFriend(event)">Link</a></p>
</div>
<div>
  <script>
      function doCreateFriend(event)
      {
          //Some code here
      }
  </script>
</div>
</body>
```

Does anyone know why and could help me ? :)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: hum, strange.. it's working for me, just copy-pasted your code in this fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/k7fnj743/

Comment: Are you adding this function to your `webview` ?